# Gitlab Terraform module init /authentication issue

Tags: gitlab, terraform

Currently having an issue pulling my own module from a gitlab terraform module registry.  Gone through the gitlab documentation but still struggling.  Gone with the instructions and using the following config:

```
module "ResourceGroup" {
  source = "gitlab.com/<myuser>/resourcegroupmodule/mysystem"
  version = "0.0.1"
  
  base_name = "TerraformExample01"
  location = "West US"
}
```

When i try and run terraform init, I get the following error:

```
│ Error: Error accessing remote module registry
│ 
│ Failed to retrieve available versions for module "ResourceGroup" (main.tf:25) from gitlab.com: error looking up module versions:
│ 401 Unauthorized.
```

Tried to add a credential block as per the instructions but no success either.  Added this block to the main.tf file:

```
credentials "gitlab.com" {
  token = "<myAPIkey>"
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Feels like kind of got the credentials section/api token in the wrong place.

Comment: What scopes did you authorize for your API key?

Comment: @sytech set to full access for the token

Comment: Looking at the access token in the Gitlab portal it's not even being used as not showing any activity.

Comment: @JohnFox, have you tried with the credentials block in `~/.terraformrc` instead of `main.tf`?

[Reference a Terraform Module](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/terraform_module_registry/index.html#reference-a-terraform-module) & Terraform [CLI Configuration File](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file)

Comment: @lyzlisa yes that did the trick and now up and running.  Got some issues with my module but that's another issue!  This credentials and authentication issue is sorted.  Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 8):

The answer is above from @lyzlisa.

Just created the ~/.terraformrc file with the credentials block

Answer (score 4):

I used environment variable TF_TOKEN_gitlab_whatever_domain_com=
Access toke with read_api permission. I have a hosted gitlab solution on gitlab.whatever.domain.com
This approach worked for me.

Comment: I can confirm this also works. Wondering where is this documented as Gitlab docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/terraform_module_registry/#reference-a-terraform-module)  don't mention this approach, only the `~/.terraformrc` approach.